# regex issue while validating the contact no

Tags: jquery, regex

i have have problem with regex while validating contact no.. cant identify what i doing wrong.. code i use as below

```
  $('#contact_no').bind('keypress', function (event) {
       var regex = new RegExp("^[+0-9\b]");
       var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
       if (!regex.test(key)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }
   });
```

what i want no is starting with +(sign) and it is mendatory **user can enter** **+xxxxxxxxxx or xxxxxxxxxx** and **+(sign) occure only once at 1st** position after that +(sign) is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var regex = /^\+?[0-9]+$/;
```

No need to use a `RegExp` object here as you can use a regex literal to do your job.

This regex allows one optional `+` at start followed by 1 or more digits.

---

**Update:**

Problem is using keypress event for binding. Which is sending each entered character to this code.

You can use:

```
$('#contact_no').bind('submit focusout', function (event) {
       var regex = /^\+?\d+$/;
       var key = $('#contact_no').val();
       if (!regex.test(key)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           console.log("Invalid value: " + key);
           return false;
       }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/03g7v226/2/)

Comment: if i press + then it is not working.. number are printed ie xxxxxxxxxx(working ) but +xxxxxxxxxx not working..

Comment: `+123456` and `123456` both should work with this. Can you print `key` just before `test` function call and see what the input string is.

Comment: [You can check this demo how this regex is working correctly](https://regex101.com/r/fP3mC3/1)

Comment: at  **regex.test(key)** when i press **+** then it will **return false** but for **number** it **return true**..

Comment: Just `+` without any number should be invalid input right?

Comment: no its mendatory if user want to put + then they can use + but if user dont want to use then start with number.. can't figure out what's the problem your code is working but only +(sign not working) at start up check fiddle [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/03g7v226/)

Comment: Problem is using `keypress` event for binding. Which is sending each entered character to this code. Check my updated answer.